# how to generate 8 digit barcode in android?

Tags: android, barcode

I want to generate custom 8 digit barcode in android. I need textview to enter custom number and generate button to create barcode and the final barcode will display on the screen. Can you help me for that?

Comment: Yeah We can definitely help you. However, we do not spoonfeed code here. Show us what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156402/Android-Generating-an-EAN-Barcode

You can get code and try it for yourself.

Comment: This code will generate barcode but the scanner could not find the value. I think this code is not correct.

Comment: Read the comments in site for more details.